# JAX-RS (Resteasy 3.5.0.Final) + Wildfly 12 + Java 9 + maven = 404 not found, but JAX-RS (Resteasy 3.5.0.Final) + Wildfly 12 + Java 8 + maven works

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I have got a simple Hello World example JAX-RS project. Really simple and stupid. Just minimal configuration, which I intend to enhance in future, just imagine something like this with : https://robferguson.org/blog/2016/12/02/getting-started-with-resteasy/ .

Well, my problem is, that when I set the Java version to "1.9", I always receive a "404 not found" error. But when I change it back to 1.8, mvn clean install and deploy, it works fine. The java version is the only delta, which makes it working or not working. How to make it work with java 9?
I do use maven 3.5 and jdk 9.0.4.

works fine:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

returns 404:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.9</source>
            <target>1.9</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Every other piece of code remains unchanged. No errors appear in the wildfly console - it acts as if the path was wrong, but it is not, because after switching back to 1.8, it works fine with the same path.

Comment: What I think is going on is that your resources are no longer begin scanned in Java 9, due to module restrictions.

Comment: Are you aware of any resources, which describe how to deal with module restrictions & JAX-RS?

Comment: This book might be helpful: https://javamodularity.com/ - the authors describe a number of situations with component scanning that fail with Java 9, unless certain measures are taken.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be related to a problem with Jandex 2.0.4, which was included in Wildfly 12. According to this ticket:

https://issues.jboss.org/projects/WFLY/issues/WFLY-9961?filter=allissues

reverting to jandex 2.0.3 will fix the issue. 
A fixed version of jandex will be included in Wildfly 13.