# JAX-RS + JDK10 = WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application, while it works fine with JDK8

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly

I want to do a POC with Wildfly 12 and Java 10.

I have a JAX-RS application configuration and just one GET endpoint, but, I'm facing below issue:

```
WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application.  In blogservice.war either provide a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application or declare a servlet class in web.xml.
```

When I run the same app (and same server WF12) with JDK8 works fine, but with JDK9 and JDK10 does not work.

I have been looking per information about this error with no results.

Any idea?

---

Below a github repo with the project I did and is not working.

https://github.com/pablobastidasv/jee8_jdk10_poc

---

I found the failure point, it was a dependency I put into the `pom.xml`, this dependency is one that I did to handle exceptions, now what I don't know is...

Why it is failing with that dependency in JDK10 but not in JDK8?

The dependency github repo is https://github.com/pablobastidasv/exceptions

This dependency has 2 custom exceptions and 3 ExceptionMapper (cdi providers).

---

After remove this dependency I don't have that error (WFLYRS0015) anymore but the JaxRs subsystem is not loaded with JDK10* but works with JDK8.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifV1D.png

Comment: Given it's just a "hello world" app, let's see your code...

Comment: @Pablo: don't use [java] tag when asking [java-ee] questions. [java] users are not per definiton capable of understanding [java-ee]. Use the one or the other, not both.

Comment: I created a `github` repo with code example. Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167695/jax-rs-resteasy-3-5-0-final-wildfly-12-java-9-maven-404-not-found-but is about same problem.

Comment: Same thing for me: Wildfly17 + Java 8 = works as expected, Wildfly17 and JDK 11 = 404

Comment: Same thing with Wildfly 22 + JDK11 when deploying from eclipse. But it is strange that it seems random. If I do some clean, rebuild, remove the .war from the wildfly and add again, eventually it starts working. It is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class in your application somewhere:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

The package doesn't matter but it needs to be part of your webapp.

The `@ApplicationPath` path is the way that the URL's are partitioned in your server.  You may set this to what you want but be careful with setting it to `/` as some versions of Wildfly and/or Wildfly Swarm have historically had problems with serving JAX-RS content and HTML type of content from the same URL prefix.  These issues may be long since fixed - I just know that I ran into it a while ago.

The main path to your services may already be in your `web.xml` in some other form and it should be removed when you create the `Application` class.  `web.xml` is, depending on your needs, optional now.

Comment: Yes, this Application class is already there, this is what make strange this behaviour, even, the same app works with JDK8 without any modification.